# Ruby on Rails - How to combine output data from 2 separate APIs and add them to database

Tags: json, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application, I need to gather some data from 2 separate (3rd party) **APIs** and add them to my database for a record for better analyzing.

Both **APIs** have the same amount of raws *(For instance, when I request `images` for Album X, it will show me data for ALL images in that album)*

So both **APIs** will have the same amount of `images` **BUT** different fields and field names.

In my application, I'm only interested in getting data for 5 fields from both **APIs**. I get `field_1`, `field_3` & `field_5` from the **first API** while I get `field_2` & `field_4` from the **second API**.

This is how I do it now to **only** get fields-value from the **first API** *(I'm still stuck for how to put both **APIs** together)*.

```
## My Image Model
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

  private

    def self.add_image_data_to_database(object, field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4, field_5)
      object.create(
          field_1: field_1,
          field_2: field_2,
          field_3: field_3,
          field_4: field_4,
          field_5: field_5,
      )
    end
end

## My Images Controller
class ImagesController < ApplicationController

  first_site_api = "api.website-1.com"
  first_api_results = HTTParty.get(first_site_api)
  first_api_json = JSON.parse(first_api_results)


  second_site_api = "api.website-2.com"
  second_api_results = HTTParty.get(second_site_api)
  second_api_json = JSON.parse(second_api_results)

  first_api_json.each do |data|
    Image.add_image_data_to_database(
        data['field_1'], 
        data['field_3'],
        data['field_5']
        )
  end

end
```

Basically what I need and wonder how to do, is to get some fields-value from the first API and some from the second API and put them together so I can add them all for 1 image.

Comment: Can you add sample for the response of each API call.

Comment: I suggest convert the response to hash then merge both hashes using merge method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get items out of a hash with `.keep_if` so you might try:

```
# My Image Model
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

  private

    def self.add_image_data_to_database(object, hash)
      object.create(hash)
    end
end

## My Images Controller
class ImagesController < ApplicationController

  first_site_api = "api.website-1.com"
  first_api_results = HTTParty.get(first_site_api)

  hash = JSON.parse(first_api_results)
           .keep_if{|k, _v| [ 'field_1', 'field_3', 'field_5'].include?(k)}


  second_site_api = "api.website-2.com"
  second_api_results = HTTParty.get(second_site_api)

  hash.merge( JSON.parse(second_api_results)
    .keep_if{|k, _v| ['field_2', 'field_4'].include?(k) }
  )

  Image.add_image_data_to_database(hash)
end
```